# Truffle and Ganache tutorial for a Solidity smart contract migration error

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, ganache

Following the tutorial on "Ethereum Development Walkthrough (Part 2: Truffle, Ganache, Geth and Mist)" I've, in broad strokes, initialized the `truffle` folder, copied over the `Wrestling.sol`, ran `compile truffle`, and, yet, after running `migrate` am not seeing any message about deploying the contract from `ganache`.

Each step has seemingly been completed correctly:

**truffle usage**

```
nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ ll
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 nicholas nicholas 4096 Apr 15 15:24 ./
drwxr-xr-x 71 nicholas nicholas 4096 Apr 15 15:18 ../
nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ truffle init

Starting init...
================

> Copying project files to /home/nicholas/truffle

Init successful, sweet!

nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ cp /home/nicholas/git/ethereum-walkthrough-1/Wrestling.sol . -vi
'/home/nicholas/git/ethereum-walkthrough-1/Wrestling.sol' -> './Wrestling.sol'
nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ ll
total 32
drwxrwxr-x  5 nicholas nicholas 4096 Apr 15 15:24 ./
drwxr-xr-x 71 nicholas nicholas 4096 Apr 15 15:18 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 nicholas nicholas 4096 Apr 15 15:24 contracts/
drwxr-xr-x  2 nicholas nicholas 4096 Apr 15 15:24 migrations/
drwxr-xr-x  2 nicholas nicholas 4096 Apr 15 15:24 test/
-rw-r--r--  1 nicholas nicholas 4598 Apr 15 15:24 truffle-config.js
-rw-rw-r--  1 nicholas nicholas 2708 Apr 15 15:24 Wrestling.sol
nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ mv truffle-config.js truffle-config.js.bkup
nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ nano truffle-config.js 
nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ cat truffle-config.js
module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // for more about customizing your Truffle configuration!
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};

nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ truffle compile

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
✔ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
✔ Downloading compiler. Attempt #1.
> Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol
> Artifacts written to /home/nicholas/truffle/build/contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang

nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ truffle migrate --network development

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.



Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'development'
> Network id:      1618525649277
> Block gas limit: 6721975 (0x6691b7)


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0xb6045e7573e3834c4c79eb935e83500974d499f9d32dd7933b3dfa1631bb681d
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > contract address:    0xebCf528c359E57f5300bD0fb1Ae2911CD7581132
   > block number:        1
   > block timestamp:     1618525749
   > account:             0xAF400c33455309896aD4A3ceF3e9b801f4b84601
   > balance:             99.99616114
   > gas used:            191943 (0x2edc7)
   > gas price:           20 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.00383886 ETH


   > Saving migration to chain.
   > Saving artifacts
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:          0.00383886 ETH


Summary
=======
> Total deployments:   1
> Final cost:          0.00383886 ETH


nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ pwd
/home/nicholas/truffle
nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$
```

**ganache console**

```
nicholas@mordor:~/truffle$ ganache-cli -p 7545
Ganache CLI v6.12.2 (ganache-core: 2.13.2)

Available Accounts
==================
(0) 0xAF400c33455309896aD4A3ceF3e9b801f4b84601 (100 ETH)
(1) 0xCCCfA7723c87e987d05FfF47Cff11387519e8977 (100 ETH)
(2) 0xe05d12C9369F0D38a9bf3E710fceF7a480808114 (100 ETH)
(3) 0xd1988F3E8f53F096024EE240c1E0a411dFcfe6aE (100 ETH)
(4) 0x234b8f036e925A15D2B2760903d8F364f41fA064 (100 ETH)
(5) 0x27B5466FF034F1904568de1500Daf0f0A70d5393 (100 ETH)
(6) 0xd969E5d5E14c85329e9369e61Ac36301BE0E4287 (100 ETH)
(7) 0xC13e11eEA25ED477cEF68b512c0Fcd6113996369 (100 ETH)
(8) 0xB2d8e219eBFE5Ee3B0E4acE09DD30bfD5881FBa5 (100 ETH)
(9) 0xC1983b4ABfC233de38E00fD3727e0461f86535ee (100 ETH)

Private Keys
==================
(0) 0xca62f6371c91ee3843fbe4764c02612b05f388394510cc4000467a719499685f
(1) 0x6016ebd988cea6f78aa232f6aab40cada947ada74f928d87de86db825b7b11e5
(2) 0x6d1cfeed4f1748cb8a685c449960023cfae4fa5a7eba0087cb24c558594d2054
(3) 0x5d99edc99844c968b380088f1856995952307b91f533198ced4a706bbada9b62
(4) 0x0c7798bd411444673a3640311dd742b7daf944a93d936047b420e50d70a9ca90
(5) 0xf25d7a8f89aa63a7fef85192d7f9108494cf855c269d941378d9d7ffbd8c161c
(6) 0x7317293b8cd55dcce8a7729bfeaacb0265522348ecfdd992e353fc4d33e5ec99
(7) 0x5d257a1fb44624c4de13fea1d75cb708b8922936565cb3fa0dabb2e218e2c6a5
(8) 0x9e758500b8cd79757bb4eb307e3c1005d66984ec38ab47de219d81d803fd994c
(9) 0xe26b033f6e307cb3fc0784fe982fc00681c37389aee79dad69b33db4d4ef050d

HD Wallet
==================
Mnemonic:      person dice develop erupt pilot purpose cool bomb inherit cloth metal canal
Base HD Path:  m/44'/60'/0'/0/{account_index}

Gas Price
==================
20000000000

Gas Limit
==================
6721975

Call Gas Limit
==================
9007199254740991

Listening on 127.0.0.1:7545
eth_blockNumber
net_version
eth_accounts
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_accounts
net_version
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_getBlockByNumber
net_version
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_estimateGas
net_version
eth_blockNumber
eth_getBlockByNumber
net_version
eth_sendTransaction

  Transaction: 0xb6045e7573e3834c4c79eb935e83500974d499f9d32dd7933b3dfa1631bb681d
  Contract created: 0xebcf528c359e57f5300bd0fb1ae2911cd7581132
  Gas usage: 191943
  Block Number: 1
  Block Time: Thu Apr 15 2021 15:29:09 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

eth_getTransactionReceipt
eth_getCode
eth_getTransactionByHash
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_getBalance
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_sendTransaction

  Transaction: 0xaefa402a80b986a218cecc26b215d3c06ccc557030bbe4bd1371978404164a64
  Gas usage: 42338
  Block Number: 2
  Block Time: Thu Apr 15 2021 15:29:09 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

eth_getTransactionReceipt
```

but perhaps either a step was skipped or done incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the `Wrestling.sol` to the `contracts` folder. And to create the deployment JS code.

---

As the [tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/ethereum-development-walkthrough-part-2-truffle-ganache-geth-and-mist-8d6320e12269) says:

> Then copy the Wrestling.sol file from the last tutorial, into the folder “contracts”.
>
> Next, open the folder “migrations” and create a new file named “2_deploy_contracts.js”. Migrations are simply scripts that’ll help us deploy our contracts to a blockchain.
>
> Paste the following code inside, and save.
>
> ```
> const Wrestling = artifacts.require("./Wrestling.sol")
>
> module.exports = function(deployer) {
>   deployer.deploy(Wrestling);
> };
> ```